# How to run a script after or before hibernate

Tags: scripts, hibernate

I want to run a 4 commands before a hibernate and another 2 commands after update. Is it also possible to arrange the time/squence of each commands,if yes then could you explain how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can run commands before and after hibernation or suspension (note there is a difference; hibernation is to disk, suspension is to memory) by creating a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in
  hibernate)
    # put commands to run on hibernation here
    ;;
  thaw)
    # put commands to run when returning from hibernation here
    ;;
  suspend)
    # put commands to run on suspend here
    ;;
  resume) 
    # put commands to run when returning from suspension
    ;;
esac
```

The filename of the script will dictate the order in which the scripts run compared to other scripts in sleep.d. Within your script, your commands will run in whatever order you put then in the script.

Comment: Could you explain why the filename has to be 'xxname' where x is a number, what does x mean?

Comment: The files are ordered (and therefore executed) in alpha-numeric order. The number is not necessary, but it provides a way of controlling the order of the scripts.

Comment: Please note that every command in the *xxname* file will be executed as `root`. So if you need to stop/start some non-system application (for example, Dropbox) run corresponding command as usual user with aid of `su` (for example, `su --command 'dropbox start' user`.

Comment: With the change to systemd, this answer is only correct for 14.04 and earlier. See [Make a script start after suspend in Ubuntu 15.04 (systemd)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/661715/make-a-script-start-after-suspend-in-ubuntu-15-04-systemd) and [man systemd-sleep](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man8/systemd-suspend.service.8.html) for later versions.