# Make a script start after suspend in Ubuntu 15.04 (systemd)

Tags: 15.04, scripts, suspend

I have a script that starts my broadband connection at start-up and I want to make it start at resume from suspend.

My script's is `/usr/local/bin/start_my_connection`

it contains:

```
#!/bin/sh
sleep 10
nmcli nm wwan on
nmcli con up id "reber connection"`
```

*What should I do to make it run using `systemd`?*

Comment: Don't know if it's relevant to systemd. Why not try putting it into `/etc/pm/sleep.d/`, and check what happens.

Comment: no it should be at /lib/systemed/systemed-sleep/ but don't know how to make it work after that.

Comment: Try [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/92218/178596) - though a deleted answer on it suggests elsewhere using another location due to [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1455097) .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two approaches to choose from:

### Using the `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` directory:

Create another script called `00start_my_connection`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = post ] && [ $2 = suspend ]
then /usr/local/bin/start_my_connection
fi
```

`$1` is "post" on resume/thaw and "pre" otherwise. In either case, `$2` contains either "suspend", "hibernate", or "hybrid-sleep".  If you want the script to also run on thaw from hibernation, leave out `&& [ $2 = suspend ]`.

Ensure this script is executable by using `chmod a+x 00start_my_connection`

Move this script into `/lib/systemd/system-sleep/` using

```
sudo mv 00start_my_connection /lib/systemd/system-sleep/
```

### Using service files:

Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/start_my_connection.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Run start_my_connection
After=suspend.target
#After=hibernate.target
#After=hybrid-sleep.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start_my_connection

[Install]
WantedBy=suspend.target
#WantedBy=hibernate.target
#WantedBy=hybrid-sleep.target
```

Uncomment all lines if you also want the script to run on thaw from hibernation.  Then install the service file with:

```
sudo systemctl enable start_my_connection.service
```

Comment: hi, the first method didn't work for me, the second one when i try to install the serves it says no such file or directory

Comment: Does the file `/etc/systemd/system/start_my_connection.service` exist?

Comment: sorry my bad, i place it at /bin/systemed not /etc/systemed . now it's installed but still doesn't reconnect after suspend.

Comment: What is the output of `journalctl -eu  start_my_connection`

Comment: it's a long list, post it here? @martin

Comment: Only from the most recent run, starting from `Aug 15 ??:??:?? ????? systemd[1]: Started Run start_my_connection.`. [Edit] it into your answer.

Comment: this is a Google docs link to it https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_QLTgHmx8yi9ACEmJZqgWFJwk9-MlsHMCoUd9D2Ue6o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27004/discussion-between-martin-thornton-and-ronniedroid).

Comment: Thank you for the great tips! it is better to have it `Before` than `After` `suspend.target`, otherwise the contents of the screen are visible for a fraction of a second after hibernation, which is a "privacy concern"

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04, nothing works except for the Service Unit option. Depending on what task is being executed in the service, especially if persistence is an issue, you might want to configure `KillMode=none/mixed/process` in the `[Service]` section...

Answer (score 3):

Create a file `01myscript` in `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` directory.

Contents of that file should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in 
    thaw|resume) /usr/local/bin/start_my_connection
    ;;
esac
```

Make that script executable: `sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/01myscript`.

Try to suspend

Comment: Is reboot or restart sleep service needed?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've not used this method for a long time but if I recall correctly no reboot or service restart was required.

Comment: I was working with this after comment and can confirm you don't need to restart `systemd-suspend.service`