# Can't run systemd based script after wake from suspend. Why?

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend, systemd

The following [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/661747) shows how to run a script after waking from suspend based on systemd. I tried them but could not get a gnome-terminal to appear to run a command.

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "$1" == "post" ]; then
  gnome-terminal --command 'compiz --replace &'
```

Why did they not work? I am using Ubuntu 16.04.2 kernel 4.8.0-45-generic. 
I am curious why my systemd based script did not work. My command works on an opened gnome-terminal but somehow won't work with systemd-suspend.service method. ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know any terminal emulators have been closed after doing their jobs.

But if you want to gnome-terminal not to be closed using this script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d` path (this script cause to keep terminal opened until you hit enter) :

```
sudo nano /etc/pm/sleep.d/myscript
```

Then paste these content to you script :

```
#!/bin/bash
case $1 in 
     thaw|resume) gnome-terminal --command 'bash -c "compiz --replace &; read line"'
     ;;
esac
```

Then make it executble by this command:

```
sudo chmod a+x /etc/pm/sleep.d/myscript
```

I hope that's work for you.

**UPDATE:**

> Thanks for sharing. I was curious why my systemd based script did not work. My command works on an opened gnome-terminal but somehow won't work with systemd-suspend.service solution. Could you try on your system to see it has any effect? You can replace the compriz command with command "sleep 20" to try. Appreciate your feedback
>   The suspend way is different on many machines some of them use `sudo pm-suspend` and some of them use `systemctl suspend` command.

We can use systemd based script if we use `systemctl suspend` for OS sleep (not to use `sudo pm-suspend`. but in some systems, when you click on suspend boton, the operating system use `pm-suspend` command).
But the systemd based scripts and powermanagement based scripts have a little difference with each other:

In systemd based script we can't run GUI applications because in that condition there is no X server for it to connect to.

So you can't use `gnome-terminal` in such commands like `gnome-terminal --command 'compiz --replace &'` . if you want to show gnome-terminal you must use powermanagement based scripts.

But in your case it's enough to use this script (without gnome-terminal):

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = post ] ; then
compiz --replace &
fi
```

And you can test your script by replacing something like `touch /home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/test.txt` instead of `compiz --replace &`:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = post ] ; then
touch /home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/test.txt
fi
```

(Be aware that because in systemd based scripts the root user run commands so do not use `~/Desktop` instead of `/home/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop` because the the root user's ~ is not your home directory !)

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I was curious why my systemd based script did not work. My command works on an opened gnome-terminal but somehow won't work with systemd-suspend.service solution. Could you try on your system to see it has any effect? You can replace the compriz command with command "sleep 20" to try. Appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I have edited my comment and answered your question

Comment: Thanks @ali . I found that `compiz --replace&` solves my display issues only when executed from a terminal. Hence, I used `gnome-terminal` to issue the command. You might want to re-check. Noted on the diff between systemd and  powermanagement. ;)

Comment: @Sun Bear . you can use ~/.xsessionrc and ~/.xsession directories instead of that ;  but as far as i know U can't run run gui applications with systemd base script