# Run a script on unlock/resume

Tags: bash, scripts, suspend

I noticed that the desktop login sound doesn't play when unlocked. I read other posts saying that putting an executable in /etc/pm/sleep.d or /lib/systemd/system-sleep will run it when you log in.

Those posts were very old (The newest was for 15.04), and the script won't run when I unlock my device. I created the script by duplicating one of the others and renamed and rewrote it to make sure I kept the right MIME type.

I can't find any log files related to suspend, so I have no idea if it's even attempting to run the script.

As of now, I'm using test scripts to make sure the executable works. It should run gedit when I unlock.

```
#! /bin/sh

# Custom script at login
case "$1" in
   suspend|hibernate)
      #do nothing
   ;;
   resume|thaw)
      gedit
   ;;
   *)
      exit 1
   ;;
esac
```

I am running Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Use this https://askubuntu.com/a/661747/15811 where `ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/start_my_connection`  needs to call the sound you want to hear

Comment: Nope... didn't work.

Comment: It won't work like that with a graphical tool like gedit. Try replacing `gedit` with `touch /tmp/newFile`. Is the `/tmp/newFile` file created?

Comment: No, nothing happened.