# Swap between 2 and 3 finger taps on touchpad is not permanent, but activated by opening the terminal

Tags: scripts, touchpad, asus, multi-touch, synaptics

I followed simple guides consisting in adding the lines

```
synclient TapButton2=2
synclient TapButton3=3
```

into a `.sh` script made executable by

```
chmod +x /home/name/touchpad.sh
```

and make it automatically run on startup with

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.peripherals.input-devices hotplug-command “/home/name/touchpad.sh”
```

Now when I recover from hibernation the two finger tap acts like the right mouse clic and the three finger tap don't do anything (at least I think), just as I changed nothing.
The behavior should be two finger tap acting like the central mouse clic and the three finger tap as the right one. **I can make the change effective by simply opening** (nothing more!) **a new terminal**.

Comment: Seems duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/308067/how-to-run-a-script-after-or-before-hibernate

Comment: That solution seems to not work for me.